# How to filter data frame by a minimal difference by groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm struggling on how can I keep on my dataframe only the elements that the difference of values in `measure` are minimal `2` for each group in `id1`. Here is a toy example:

```
test = data.frame(measure = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 0, 1),
                  id1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "D"),
                  id2 = c("16", "16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "18"))
# > test
#   measure id1 id2
# 1       1   A  16
# 2       2   B  16
# 3       3   A  16
# 4       2   B  16
# 5       2   C  17
# 6       4   C  17
# 7       0   A  17
# 8       1   D  18

#as result, I'd like something like
#> res
#   measure id1 id2
# 1       1   A  16
# 3       3   A  16
# 5       2   C  17
# 6       4   C  17
# 7       0   A  17
```

The `id1` equal `A` and `D` where removed, since their `max(value) - min(value) < 2`.

Any hint on how can I apply this?

Comment: Should the removal be done also by grouping `measure`? Or the column `measure` is to be ignored?

Comment: @PaulSmith The column `measure` will be used to calculate the min and max, the group_by should use the `id1`.

Comment: something like: `if(max(value) - min(value) >= 2` by each `id1` we keep them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `tidyverse` option.

```
test %>% 
  group_by(id1) %>% 
  filter((max(measure)- min(measure)) >= 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Quixotic22: I have just learned from you that one can here dispense with `c_across`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

test = data.frame(measure = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 0, 1),
                  id1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "D"),
                  id2 = c("16", "16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "18"))

test %>% 
  group_by(id1) %>% 
  mutate(aux = (max(c_across(measure))- min(c_across(measure))) >= 2) %>% 
  ungroup %>% filter(aux) %>% select(-aux)

#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   measure id1   id2  
#>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1       1 A     16   
#> 2       3 A     16   
#> 3       2 C     17   
#> 4       4 C     17   
#> 5       0 A     17
```

Answer (score 1):

The data.table structure provides an option here.

```
# Load library
library(data.table)
# Create data.table
test <- 
  data.table(measure = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 0, 1),
             id1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "D"),
             id2 = c("16", "16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "18"))
# Solution:
test[id1 %in% test[, .(max(measure)-min(measure)), by=id1][V1>=2, id1]]
```

In this solution, `test[, .(max(measure)-min(measure)), by=id1]` is giving a data.table of differences and `[V1>=2, id1]` is subsetting that and returning a vector of valid id1 values. The `id1 %in%` then subsets the original data on the contents of that vector.

The result is:

```
 measure id1 id2
1:       1   A  16
2:       3   A  16
3:       2   C  17
4:       4   C  17
5:       0   A  17
```

---

**A mini data.table lesson:**

- With data.tables, we use the notation `DT[i, j, by]` where:

  - `DT` is the data.table
  - `i` is the operations on observations (e.g. filter, sort)
  - `j` is the operations on variables (e.g. select, process)
  - `by` (and `keyby`) provides grouping for the `j`-operations
- data.tables have some special characters including

  - `.N` for "number of observations"
  - `.SD` for "selected variables"
- Install and load the data.table package to use this structure.
- Convert an existing data.frame, list or tibble into a data.table using `setDT()` or `data.table()`
- Use `fread()` to read external data files directly into a data.table.

*An example* - To get the number of cars and mean fuel efficiency of cars from mtcars, where hp>100 and summary stats grouped by number of cylinders:

```
dtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
dtcars[hp>100, .("n" = .N, "mean_mpg" = mean(mpg)), keyby=cyl]
```